# How to save a file including a user-input year in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, user-input

I am new to Python and programming in general and would really appreciate guidance on this probably very simple question.

I use the code:

```
year = input (Choose a year between 2001 and 2010)
```

Then I want to append these to an empty list under names including that year (the files under these names for 2001 to 2010  such as 2003_woodland.shp already exist in my work space)

```
File_list = [ ]

File_list.append(path+ "{year}_woodland.shp")

File_list.append(path + "{year}perimeters.shp")
```

How do I format it to grab the year that was input by the user? Do I need to make a loop?

Answer (score 0):

To insert a string into another string this syntax is used:

```
string2 = 'hello world'
print('contents of string2: %s' % string2)
```

Only minor changes need to be made to your code:

```
year = input('Choose a year between 2001 and 2010: ')

File_list = [ ]

File_list.append(path + ("%s_woodland.shp" % year))

File_list.append(path + ("%sperimeters.shp" % year))
```

Comment: This also works with other literals, for example: `'five: %i' % 5`.

Note that the letter after the % sign is the first letter of the literal type: %s for string, %i for integer, %f for float, ect.